Python files not opening after crash : Errno60 Operation timed out
My computer crashed while running a jupyter notebook. This notebook was using a .py file. I restarted my computer, but now the .py file won't open, not with jupyter nor with any other IDE or notepad or anything... I cannot even send it by mail. When I try to open it I get a timeout error. Anyone had this problem before? Is there a solution?
Thank you very much
I tried opening with different ides

Were you writing to the .py file? It sounds like you may have made a huge file and it won't open. Or you changed the permissions? Or if it wasn't closed right when your computer crashed, is it possible it became corrupted? What is the file size? Do you have a terminal and can try to look at the header or tail of this file? Do you have any problem creating and using a new .py file?

how many lines of code was the file ?  can you open it in notepad (or any basic editor) ?
